# How to get the cache statistical data in Mule 4

Tags: caching, mule, ehcache, mule-component

We are migrating from Mule 3.8.3 to Mule 4.1.4. While caching in Mule 3.8.3, we were referencing the object store which in turn was referencing to a spring bean that implemented the ehcache for custom object store. In other flow we had a invoke component to invoke spring bean whose java class has the method `CacheManager.getCache(cacheName).getStatistics()` of EhCache to get the Cache hit statistics. But in Mule 4 we are unable to create an custom object store(with the flexibility provided by java class) for custom caching strategy. Is there a way in Mule 4 Object store to reference to our bean to implement the custom caching strategy.? We might as well use the inhouse persistent object store but it does not provide the same flexibilty as we had by referencing a EhCache implementation class.

Also, with Mule 3.8.3 we were also setting the `setMaxEntriesLocalHeap` and `setTimeToLiveSeconds` in the java class which provided the flexibility of modifying the cache coonfigurations on the fly when the mule app is already deployed. This also is not possible with mule 4 as the custom object store can only be set from the Mule end (which will be set at deployment time and hence no modifications can be made on the fly when app is deployed) and not by any java class.

Any help is much appreciated.